# ¿Problemas con variables de sesión ASP . NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Qué tal, buen día. Tengo problemas para cerrar sesión correctamente en mi aplicación.
Lo que quiero es que una vez que cierre sesión me dirija a la página de Login, pero además cuando pulse el botón hacia atrás no me regrese a la página anterior.
El problema aquí son esas variables, porque me marcan error de referencia nula, porque ya se destruyeron anteriormente.

¿Qué procede en éstos casos?

En el botón de cerrar sesión tengo lo siguiente:

```
Session.Clear();
Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx", false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que deberías hacer es poner una validación en todas tus páginas, primero en el login, exactamente en su evento load debes borrar la variable de sesión o cookie que tengas, para evitar problemas y conflictos al ingresar otros usuarios, segundo en los demás formularios pon una restricción de que si no existe la variable de sesión o está en nulo re direccione al login, con esto evitaras errores, ya que, las variables de sesión duran muy poco, y cuando se haya acabado su tiempo de duración te arrojará error, puesto que la variable de sesión estará vacía o destruida, para ello en el usuario tendrá que acceder nuevamente (esto puede evitarse empleando cookies).

**Código en el login**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        if (Request.Cookies["idUserCookie"] != null)
            {
                HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("idUserCookie");
                myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
                Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
            }
        if ((string)Session["IdUser"]   != null)
            Session.Remove("IdUser");
    }
}
```

**Código en los demás formularios**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["IdUser"] == null)
        Response.Redirect("~/Acceso");
}
```

**Método para validar el acceso del usuario, de tipo web services, se puede usar  con JavaScript y Ajax, comúnmente usado para ejecutar efectos (pop-ups, mensajes, barras de carga, etc) y eventos de teclado**

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static bool EventValidarAcceso(string paramIdCliente) {
    bool resultado = false; // {comprobar existencia de cuenta}
    Cliente cliente = new Cliente()
    { 
        IdCliente = paramIdCliente,
        Contrasenia = paramContrasenia 
    };
    if (cliente.ValidarAcceso("RW_Security_Check_User")) // Ingresa a este IF sólo si el usuario y contraseña son correctos
    {
        resultado                                   = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Session["IdUser"]       = paramIdCliente;
        HttpCookie MyCookie = new HttpCookie("idUserCookie");
        MyCookie.Value = paramIdCliente;
        MyCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(MyCookie);
    }
    else
        resultado = false;
    return resultado;
}
```

**Método para validar el acceso del usuario solo con backend**

```
public void EventValidarAcceso(string paramIdCliente) {
    Cliente cliente = new Cliente()
    { 
        IdCliente = paramIdCliente,
        Contrasenia = paramContrasenia 
    };
    //cliente.ValidarAcceso es el método con el cual validas el acceso a tu usuario
    // debería retornar TRUE en caso de que su acceso sea correcto
    if (cliente.ValidarAcceso("RW_Security_Check_User"))
    {
        Session["IdUser"]       = paramIdCliente;
        Response.Redirect("~/TuPaginaAMostrar.aspx", false);
    }
    else
        Response.Write("Error de autenticación");
}
```

**P.S.: Nunca pongas variables de sesión en el MASTER PAGE**

Comment: Disculpa, la variable "idUserCookie" ¿de dónde la obtiene? ¿La variable ID del usuario? ¿O es una nueva creada?

Comment: Al momento de validar el logeo se asigna el valor de la variable de sesión o cookie. Editaré la pregunta para despejar la duda. Sólo por curiosidad, empleas Ajax en tu login, para invocar tu método de logeo?

Comment: Hola, no. Para invocar el método de Logeo sólo valido la variable de sesión y para la invocación a la BD utilizo un DataSource. Es parte del código:     if (Session["IdUsuario"] != null)
                         {
                             Session["IdUsuario"] = IdUsuario.ToString();
                         }

                         else
                         {
                             Session.Add("IdUsuario", IdUsuario.ToString());
                         } 
                    Response.Redirect("~/Reportes.aspx");

Comment: Te dejé dos formas de como manejar tu logeo, espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a checar. Saludos.

Comment: Olvidaba decirte, en tu botón de cerrar sesión, sólo re-direcciona al login, con esto se limpiará la variable de sesión.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó a la perfección la parte de re-direccionar a Login en cada uno de los formularios. Eres genial.

Comment: Que bueno que te funcionó ;)

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución es que una vez que tu aplicación entre a la página de Login deshabilites la navegación hacia atrás, es decir, el botón para regresar ya no estará disponible.

Agrega el siguiente *script* al inicio de tu .aspx, en la sección del `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function DisableBackButton() {
        window.history.forward()
    }
    DisableBackButton();
    window.onload = DisableBackButton;
    window.onpageshow = function (evt) {
        if (evt.persisted)
            DisableBackButton()
    }
    window.onunload = function () {
        void(0)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hola, aquí la cuestión es que estoy utilizando un Master Page para la aplicación. Ya lo inserté en el Site Master, y también en el Login.aspx, pero ninguno funciona, ¿Qué me recomiendas hacer? ¿Habrá otra manera de controlar éstas variables de sesión?

Comment: De hecho, solo tendría que ir en el Login. Intenta limpiar los archivos temporales referentes a tu aplicación, es posible que se hayan quedado almacenados en caché